# Stacked Bar Chart from List

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I have the following matrix

```
  IdCarrefour 10 11 12 13
1           2  3  8  5 NA
2           4 NA  4  1 NA
3           5 NA NA NA NA
4           6 NA  4  1 NA
5           7 NA NA NA NA
```

For each colomn I want to how many NA and how many non-NAs I got. So I used the `apply` function:

```
mTF<-apply(m,2,function(x) table(!is.na(x)))
> str(mTF)
List of 5
 $ IdCarrefour: 'table' int [1(1d)] 5
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr "TRUE"
 $ 10         : 'table' int [1:2(1d)] 4 1
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "FALSE" "TRUE"
```

Where mTF is a list. Now I want to draw a stacked bar chart using `ggplot`.
[image]

So I have tried to convert mTF to a data.frame. With the help of other related posts I have come up with these two methods:

```
data.frame(matrix(unlist(mTF), nrow=5, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Warning message:
In matrix(unlist(mTF), nrow = 5, byrow = T) :
  data length [8] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [5]
```

Not working for me since I do not have the same factor for each level (see warning)

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, mTF)
```

Not working either since it duplicates the levels that are missing (for the last row, I should have 0 T and 5 F).

```
            c.5L..4L..2L..2L..5L. c.5L..1L..3L..3L..5L.
IdCarrefour                     5                     5
10                              4                     1
11                              2                     3
12                              2                     3
13                              5                     5
```

So Is there a way to convert my list (mTF) into a data.frame that I can use to plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to perform some operations on your data. Note that I've converted your matrix to a `data.frame` called `df`:

```
df

  IdCarrefour X10 X11 X12 X13
1           2   3   8   5  NA
2           4  NA   4   1  NA
3           5  NA  NA  NA  NA
4           6  NA   4   1  NA
5           7  NA  NA  NA  NA
#create new data.frame
df2 <- rbind(
            stack(apply(df, 2, FUN = function(x) sum(is.na(x)))), #NA
            stack(apply(df, 2, FUN = function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))) #not NA
            )
df2

   values         ind
1       0 IdCarrefour
2       4         X10
3       2         X11
4       2         X12
5       5         X13
6       5 IdCarrefour
7       1         X10
8       3         X11
9       3         X12
10      0         X13
#add indicator column
df2 <- data.frame(df2, Indicator = rep(c('NA','Not NA'), each = 5))
#remove IdCarrefour
df2 <- subset(df2, ind != 'IdCarrefour')
#make plot
ggplot(df2, aes(x = ind, y = values))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = Indicator))
```

[image]